# why appended element remove the space between the elements?

Tags: jquery

I've applied `appendTo()` jquery function but I would like to know why the image has not space between the images. You can see in the demo the appended image is removing the gap.

```
var m = $('#main');
m.find('img:lt(3)').clone().appendTo(m);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Wd38/7/)

---

Ok I got it now. But how can I append with the space?

Comment: The gap is from the whitespace in your HTLML markup. `appendTo` does not add any whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a controlled gap between the images, then apply a margin or padding to the images.

Browsers will put a gap between two images that have whitespace in the HTML between them.  When you add the images programmatically, there is no whitespace between them and thus no gap.

You can even shrink the existing whitespace down to nothing by setting a font-size: 0 or by eliminating the whitespace in the HTML.

```
img {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 3px;
}

#main {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Here's a demo of equal spacing among all the images: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/sHnS3/

Comment: But having margin and padding doesn't show equall space ... http://jsfiddle.net/8Wd38/12/

Comment: @C-Link - you should get rid of the whitespace in the original images so you can control all of them equally with padding or margin.  Then they will be identical.  See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/sHnS3/

Comment: @C-Link - demo link added to my previous comment and to my answer.

Comment: is there any other idea without font-size:0

Comment: @C-Link - you could programmatically remove the text nodes between the images or remove all whitespace between them in the HTML, but I find it easier to just put a div around the images and use `font-size: 0` there.  Works fine every time for me.

Comment: @C-Link - why do you need to do it the hard way?  You have to walk all the children of #main, find all the text nodes and remove them of set `style.fontSize = 0;` on the #main object.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are cloning only the `images` see you have used a `line-break` in each `image` So the `cloning` is done only for `images` not `line-breaks`

If you see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/SQKDf/) without `line-breaks` then you will see there is `space` between them
And you want to give `same space` for each `image` then use `padding:3px` like,

```
img{
    width: 100px; 
    padding:3px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/SQKDf/1/)

**Updated,** you can do it by `jquery` without `paading` like,

```
var m = $('#main');
var n=m.clone();
n.find(':gt(2)').remove();
$(n.html()).appendTo(m);
```

[Demo with jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/SQKDf/10/)

**But** I suggest use `CSS` if is no necessary in `jquery`

Comment: so how can i append the elements with line-breaks

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding float: left; in the img class css

Answer (score 0):

Jquery cloning eliminate the space/line breaks between the html elements.